# Default for relative addressing on JScript inside XSLT on Msxml

Tags: xslt, asp-classic, jscript, msxml

Using JScript inside an XSLT (on a Windows Server 2003 or 2008, using msxml), I am now trying to accomplish some simple file operations.  What's the default place where JScript relative addressing initializes--I would have thought it's the same place the XSLT is run from?  That file I'm looking for absolutely exists, but the function never returns FileExists properly.

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
    <![CDATA[
    function filecheck(x) {
        var f = 'default.asp';
        fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
        s = fso.FileExists(f);
        return(s);
    }
    ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

The call to it looks like `<xsl:value-of select="user:filecheck(string('foo'))"/>` and the call / return works just fine.  The problem I'm having lies in the JScript.

Thank you Stackoverflow!

Comment: Add `var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); WScript.Echo(oShell.CurrentDirectory);` to your script - what does it show?

Comment: Hi Helen.  It returns the value `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv`  This is a great clue, any suggestions to keep going?  The code in JScript that I used looks like `shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); s = shell.CurrentDirectory; return(s);`

Comment: This is the working folder for your JScript code. I don't know if this path is default for cases like yours, though. But `CurrentDirectory` is read-write, so you can change it as needed: `var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); shell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\MyFolder\\";`

Answer (score 0):

What I found, which may not be the only way to tackle it, was to use `xslProc.addParameter "PhysicalApplicationPath", Server.MapPath("~/")` inside of the Classic ASP VB code that spawns the XSLT transform.  That generates a string e.g. `I:\Websites\foo\bar\~` that once decoded and transformed a bit the JScript can use as the beginning of the full path it requires.  I couldn't seem to get this done inside the JScript itself.  I haven't tested this on a variety of Windows servers and app-hosting subelements of Windows, so I cannot say if it'd work universally or return various results.